# S.M.A.R.T spin retry count

Tags: hard-drive, smart

Monitoring the spin retry count of a 2-months-old HDD I don't fully trust (noise), I wonder:

If "current" is 134, why is "worst" indicated as 100 and "threshold" as 30? As I understand that value, lower is better.

Comment: Please post the output of `smartctl --all <dev>`

Comment: @shodanshok: The drive died in the meantime, so unfortunately I'm unable. If you deem it possible, I'd still be curious about an answer of how that spin-retry-count works..

Comment: From [here:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.#ATA_S.M.A.R.T._attributes) "Count of retry of spin start attempts. This attribute stores a total count of the spin start attempts to reach the fully operational speed (under the condition that the first attempt was unsuccessful). An increase of this attribute value is a sign of problems in the hard disk mechanical subsystem."